# Prevent VBscript app from showing Console Window

Tags: vbscript

I have a VBScript app which create Symbolic Links.

```
Set wshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
.....
linkcmd = "mklink /D """ & linkFolderPath & "\" & linkName & """ """ & libfolder & "\" & folderName & """"
    cmd = "cmd /C " & linkcmd
    wshell.Run cmd, 4, true
```

This is fine and works, but when I create a lot of links, each execution of the `wshell.Run` command results in a transient console window appearing and promptly vanishing.

Is there anyway to prevent the console window from being created so visibly?

Comment: [`Run` method reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use this VBScript to run cmd commands hidden, just incorporate it into your script:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "cmd /c yourcommands", 0, True
```

Comment: Antivirus will not like this