# How to get rid of a VBS command shell while calling in from python

Tags: python-3.x, vbscript

I am trying to create a speak application by using a VBScript instead of using the pyttsx3 python library. My application works very well but whenever I call the VBS from python, an extra command window pops up which I don't want.

My python code:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('cmd /c TextSpeak.vbs')
```

Here's what I tried:

```
import subprocess
console = subprocess.call('cmd /c TextSpeak.vbs')
CREATE_NO_WINDOW = 0x08000000
subprocess.call('taskkill /F /IM exename.exe', creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
```

It opens VBS shell which I don't need and it quite annoying.

Any help?

Code example will be more helpful Thanks.

Comment: `cmd /c TextSpeak.vbs` -> `TextSpeak.vbs`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run a command silently in VBScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39042916/how-can-i-run-a-command-silently-in-vbscript)

Comment: @ÉtienneLaneville That does not work.. while calling the vbs from python code... it still pops up console

Comment: Sorry about that. It seems like a frequent question, I saw a lot of different approaches when researching your question. Good luck!