# Hide the console window on an exe

Tags: c++

Ive written an exe in c++ that displays a message box when opened, the problem is that when I open the exe the console window also opens. I copied some code that hides it from the code, but it still flashes for half a second. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: What OS? If you're on Windows, what compiler?

Comment: The easiest way is probably to create a non-console project. But if you search a little there are compiler and linker flags that will make a Windows UI executable instead of a console executable. Assuming Windows of course.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I use mingw and im running windows

Comment: Your app started from `main` that's why you are seeing that console window. If you start your app with `WinMain` then the console window won't show up

Comment: there are a lot of duplicates: [Compiling a Win32 GUI app (without a console) using MinGW and Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7474504/995714), [Win32 programming hiding console window](https://stackoverflow.com/q/622592/995714)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on Windows, and use **MinGW GCC** (or Clang with GCC's libraries), pass `-mwindows` flag to the linker.

Answer (score 0):

Windows ? I think you are creating a console app, and the console comes with it.

IMHO, there are two possible ways for you to do:

1. Using a script to start your app, as suggested in [Prevent VBscript app from showing Console Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142603/prevent-vbscript-app-from-showing-console-window)
2. create a Window App;